# Excel macro slow with many sheets

Tags: excel, vba

At work I use a VBA macro in Excel that for each row from a table, it needs to produce a single sheet with a specific format.

I have a working code that runs fine but the problem I'm getting is that each new sheet takes longer to get copied at a quadratic pace, which means that the whole process scales as the 3rd power of the amount of rows, which is not acceptable.

run time with different methods:

[image: run time with different methods]

I've been timing different parts of the code and concluded that the problem is the timing increases as a function of the amount of sheets in the document (if I delete each new sheet before creating a new one, then there's no quadratic increase in time). Creating a new sheet and then copying from the Template sheet seems a little faster but is a marginal improvement and the resulting sheet is not properly formatted.

This is the relevant part of my code:

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
CalcState = Application.Calculation
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.DisplayStatusBar = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = False

For i = start To end
        ' Create new sheet from template
        Worksheets("Template").Copy After:=Worksheets(numsheets) 
        numsheets = numsheets + 1

        ' Change sheet's name
        item_index = Worksheets("Table").Cells(i, item).Value            
        name = "Item " & item_index
        ActiveSheet().Name = name

        ' Insert data
        Worksheets(name).Range("I30").Value = i

    End If
Next i

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = CalcState
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
```

Is there any way to optimise this so that I don't get this cubic increase in running time?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because better suited for [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I do this at work using the filter and an array. I pass the filter criteria and then once the data is filtered I copy and paste visible cells into a new sheet. It works really quickly. It could be off the beating track but I said I would mention.

Comment: How many new sheets are you creating in a single run?

Comment: @TimWilliams It depends on the project. On small ones, around 50 - 100. The problem is when there are big ones with ~600 sheets.

Comment: I know this isn't going to help much but do you really need to create 600 sheets?  What are you going to do with them ?

Comment: Unfortunately, I need to create those pages and then print them. It's for government biddings.

Comment: The only solution I can think of is to copy some of them to new workbooks.   For example every 100 or if you can group them by type.

Comment: or maybe you can keep them on one sheet and insert multiple [Page Breaks](http://www.excel-easy.com/examples/page-breaks.html) so that each row is printed on a separate page.

Answer (score 0):

Write Option Explicit On before the sub line starts at the very top of your code.

Place Application.ScreenUpdating = False directly after the sub line.

Place Application.ScreenUpdating = True directly before the End Sub line.

Declare all your variables.

Use conversion functions for variant variables.

Comment: Thanks. I've already had ScreenUpdating turned False and some variables declared. I did declared every one and turn on option explicit but the problem still there.

Answer (score 0):

I would load all the names into an array first, to avoid having to reference them individually, something like:

```
`dim arrNames    As variant

Set arrNames = range(*itemlist*).value`
```

Also, in project explorer, I would rename the template to wksTemplate, to make references a bit faster.  I think you can set a reference to each sheet as you create them:

```
Set wksNew = wksTemplate.copy....

Then use that reference:

With wksNew
    .name = arrNames(I,1)
    .range("I30").value = i
End with
```

That might help marginally.